# Does Rails 3.2+ require a join table *in addition to* declaring the has_and_belongs_to_many relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relational-database

I have a number of many-to-many relationships in my app.

I do not need to store information about the relationships themselves, so am using the `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation in my models.

I've read the Active Record documentation and it seems to confirm my strategy, **BUT** I'm not clear if I still need to create join tables in the database or if ActiveRecord in Rails 3.2 is smart enough to handle it using the model relations alone.

Any references or explanations would be appreciated.

----- Break -----

If I did need to store data about the relationship itself and I were using `has_many => through` in my model, would I need to remove the Primary Key from the "through" table (e.g. so that it only has the two foreign keys?)

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps this is obvious, but have you tried it to see if it works?

Comment: It's worked for what I've asked of it, but (because I'm new) I don't know if that proves it will always work. I'd want to understand the theory so to avoid building something that might break when using it in a way I hadn't "guess and checked".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to create the join table for a has_and_belongs_to_many association. Remember in Rails you need to 'migrate to create'. Using [this article](http://mikewilliamson.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/rails-has_and_belongs_to_many/) as an example, say we have an `Account` model and a `Role` model, we can create a join table through this migration:

```
rails generate migration create_accounts_roles_join_table
```

Now we will edit the migration file that was just created

```
create_table :accounts_roles, :id => false do |t|
  t.integer :account_id
  t.integer :role_id
end
```

It is important to include `:id => false` as this will leave off the primary key that is normally generated when you create a table. Also, we specified the two foreign keys `account_id` and `role_id`.

run `rake db:migrate` and add the HABTM associations in both models and everything is set up.

Also, as a side note, adding `join_table` to the end of the migration generator is not required but is more descriptive and `integer` can be replaced with `references` when adding the foreign keys. They are equivalent but maybe a bit more descriptive.

On the second part of your question, you don't need to remove the primary key from the table.

Comment: Thank you, fontno.  The more I read/learn, the more it seems the simple 'join table' method is being abandoned in favor of the `through:` method, but the HABTM seems cleaner to me if I'm positive there will never been info *about the relationship* that needs to be stored.

Comment: No problem. Yes :through is usually preferred HABTM. This is a good summary from [the rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many). "The simplest rule of thumb is that you should set up a has_many :through relationship if you need to work with the relationship model as an independent entity. If you don’t need to do anything with the relationship model, it may be simpler to set up a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship (though you’ll need to remember to create the joining table in the database)". Stick with it